# Camel route to read data from H2 DB in Spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, h2

My spring boot app is using route to read from mySQL DB.

```
from("sql:select * from Students?repeatCount=1").convertBodyTo(String.class)
       .to("file:outbox");
```

Now I want to create route to read from in memory H2 DB but Im not sure which camel components to use and how to create the route.

Answer (score 0):

If you got Spring Boot, then you can actually inject everything via the `dataSource=#mysql` parameter and introduce separate DataSource-Beans and use the required ones:

```java
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name = "mysqlProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.mysql")
    public DataSourceProperties mysqlDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "mysql")
    public DataSource mysqlDataSource(@Qualifier("mysqlProperties") DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return properties
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "h2Properties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.h2")
    public DataSourceProperties h2DataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "h2")
    public DataSource h2DataSource(@Qualifier("h2Properties") DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return properties
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .build();
    }

}
```

Afterwards you can declare the different DataSources in you `application.yml` but don't forget to disable/exclude the datasource autoconfig.

```yaml
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
  datasource:
    mysql:
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
      username: user
      password: pass
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    h2:
      url: jdbc:h2:mem:h2testdb
      username: sa
      password: sa
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

Your Camel-Route should look like this to use everything properly:

```java
from("sql:select * from Students?repeatCount=1&dataSource=#mysql")
.convertBodyTo(String.class)
       .to("file:outbox");
```